# How do I get rid of these CSS warnings in my JavaFX custom control?

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

I am currently developing a custom JavaFX 8 control and was about to make the first release available when Oracle released JDK u20. After upgrading to this version my control now triggers a long list of CSS warnings that look like this:

> "Could not resolve '`-fx-base`' while resolving lookups for
>   '`-fx-background-color`' from rule '`*.test`' in stylesheet
>   `test.css`".

**Note:** I am not calling any of these suspicious methods: `applyCSS()`, `layout()`, or `impl_processCSS()`.

What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: Can you post a simple example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: No I cannot. Simple examples do not trigger these messages. If you want to you can download my framework from flexganttfx.com and run the tutorial file.

Comment: i got this message ones, i do not remeber how i fixed this. but i know that this has not directly to do with the style. if i remind to the solution, i will get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages were caused by changes made by Oracle to the CSS engine. Custom controls that implemented the method Control.getUserAgentStylesheet() were likely to trigger them. There were a couple of work-arounds that were suggested to fix this but in the meantime release 8u40 moved the method to Region and it is now fully supported again. However, if your project also uses ControlsFX then you will still see them until you upgrade to ControlsFX 8.40.9.